# Skipping error value from combineLatest Observables

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am combining some Observables and I would like to skip anyone that returns an error so that the Observable can run completely

```
let observable = Observable.combineLatest(
            remoteRepository.getxx1(),
            remoteRepository.getxx2(),
            remoteRepository.getxx3()
        ) { [weak self] xx1, xx2, xx3 in

            guard let self = self else { return }

        }

        runObservable(observable: observable)
```

The getxx3() gives an error and as result, the process does not complete. How can I move on if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't at all interested in what the error was, then you can just catch the error and emit a completed event on each sub-observable. Like this:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    remoteRepository.getxx1().catch { _ in .empty() },
    remoteRepository.getxx2().catch { _ in .empty() },
    remoteRepository.getxx3().catch { _ in .empty() }
)
```

With the above, if any of the getters emits an error, the `catch` operator will catch it and the `empty()` operator will emit a completed event instead. That will allow the other observables to finish their work and complete as well.

Comment: there's not .catch on the observable it is .catchError

Comment: If you are using RxSwift 5 then it would be `catchError` instead.

Comment: The getxx2 still prevents the getxx3 from running so the action does not complete still.

Comment: You will have to show your code, because what I posted above doesn't do that.